# Iphone dev - IBAction and @property

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting

In this code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
  UILabel *labelsText;
}

@property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelsText;

-(IBAction) clicked: (id) sender;

@end
```

1.
The line with @property..
As I understood it was @property(blabla) datatype variable
But the code has 3 stuff?
IBoutlet, UIlabel and *labelsText

2.
The function clicked will change the labels content depending on which button was pressed, as both buttons are connected to that functions.
But it returns an IBAction? The code to change the labels text is in the function, it never returns anything? Could it as easily be -(void) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining a property .. you don't need to declare it as a member variable..

so

```
  UILabel *labelsText;
```

is not required...

`IBAction` is exactly like `void` except it is special way to communicate to you that this function is attached to a component in xib files

*edit :* // update /..correction ..thanks to  BJ Homer

property are the easy way to generate setter and getter methods for your variables and objects..
so instead of maybe 10 lines of code..
you can too it in only 4 lines...

```
@property peopertyname
@synthesize peopertyname
[self setpropertyname:nil]; // in viewdidUnload
[propertyname release]; // dealloc
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your last edit, with the self.propertyname. Are those done automatically?

Comment: my last edit is for non-ARC code...in any case..it will give you the ideawhat exactly happens when you create a properly..

Comment: Your @property examples are incorrect. The compiler doesn't generate a `-set:` method; it would generate a `-setPropertyName:` method. And you should never call `release` on the return value of a property accessor; it may have returned a copy of the underlying ivar, for example, in which case you'd be releasing the wrong object. In dealloc, you just want to access the ivar directly.

Answer (score 6):

IBOutlet and IBAction are both ugly hacks that we're stuck with for historical reasons. Traditionally, they were defined like this:

```
#define IBOutlet
#define IBAction void
```

So IBOutlet disappeared from the compiled code entirely, and IBAction was exactly the same as `void`. Their existence is due to the fact that Apple couldn't embed GCC directly into Interface Builder due to GPL licensing restrictions. But IB needed to be able to parse header files in order to know what outlets and actions were available on any given class. Rather than implement an entire Obj-C(++) parser just for IB, they introduced these keywords that IB could look for in the raw headers, and then just parse that one declaration.

With the advent of the LLVM compiler, things have changed. Now that a full parser is available to IB, the definitions of `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` are as follows:

```
#define IBOutlet __attribute__((iboutlet))
#define IBAction void)__attribute__((ibaction)
```

So they're both still "irrelevant" at compile time, but now they're captured via the `__attribute__(())` syntax, which is a mechanism for recording metadata about declarations. IB can find them with full compiler support, and everyone is happy.

Comment: In the tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZrMt0qVf58&feature=relmfu A comment said: "in the last example, why don't you add an outlet for buttons?
imho, outlet is for code -> object, action is for object -> code(field)."

What does he mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

IBOutlet and IBAction mean nothing, and in fact they're stripped by the precompiler (they're #defined as nothing and void, respectively).

IBOutlet is a special instruction to Xcode that you intend to use that property as an outlet in Interface Builder. IBAction is the same thing for action targets (button touch, etc.).